# Television show similar to Supernatural

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I saw an episode of a TV episode a few years ago. I've asked about it on other sites and got almost unanimously pointed to *Supernatural*. However, I've been watching *Supernatural* and I'm up to season 7, and I'm pretty sure I'm up to episodes that aired after I saw this other episode. Here's what I remember:

1. Young girl (anywhere from 9-14) is helping an older woman (aunt? grandmother?) tend to plants in a greenhouse. Older woman leaves. A deranged-looking man shows up. Confidently, the girl asks the guy if he thinks he's going to try to sexually assault her, in some sarcastic way. The guy's plan was exactly that, so it would seem, so he chases after her.
2. A couple people (guys, I think, but could have been a guy and a girl) are from out of town and are interviewing people in town. It's a woody town, somewhere up north. No idea where. Could be Oregon, could be Montana, could be Vermont. They interview people (the girl's parents?) in a house and they interview a local business owner in a general store.
3. At the end of the episode, a guy closes a trunk lid to a classic car. I don't remember the color, the make, or the model. I think I remember them putting someone (a body, a living person like a suspect) in the trunk, but I can't be sure.

Like I said, sounds a lot like *Supernatural,* especially if the car in #3 is a black '67 Impala and the people in #2 were two brothers in their 20s/30s. Both are possible.

Thing is, I was at my brother-in-law's place, and it sounded like a cool episode. It got me into *Supernatural,* and even though I didn't get a hit, I'm enjoying the show. The show I remember didn't have angels, or demons, but there was a supernatural element to the crime. I vaguely remember maybe the plants were special, or maybe the girl had the *a terrible secret* trope, like a monster in disguise or something. Or maybe the guy was the monster. Anyway, the curiosity is bothering me, so I thought I'd cast a net.

Comment: -1, purely for suggesting two of my all time favourite shows in Buffy and Angel are more more for girls!! (I am of course joking :))

Comment: I have a vague memory of the events you describe. Maybe there was something with the plants soil.. I see various potted plants in the greenhouse .. Great, now it bugs me as well :D

Comment: I apologize just the same Andrew, but understand, I classified Alias the same and enjoyed that show. Npst, that's possible, sort of a killer plants scenario. Like human traps rather than fly traps. I remember someone got got, so you could be right.

Comment: *Angel* had many characters and they drove a classic car ('68 PLymouth Belvedere  http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4142/4758222519_729efe4834_z.jpg). I can't remember an episode like you describe, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: As Sam's answer indicated, your numbered list fits s2e1 of Justified extremely well ... the only hiccup might be whatever you mean by "up north" - but after all, eastern Kentucky is technically north of a few places.

Comment: OTOH, your closing paragraph throws one off that scent: in the show we're thinking of, there is no supernatural element; the girl is mysterious in that her connection to some other characters isn't perfectly clear; her life is theoretically dangerous in that she tends an illegal growing operation, and an associated creep has unsavory designs on her; her father dies in a way that may seem mysterious or surprising, but can be explained by clever poisoning.  I'd recommend at least borrowing season 2 from the library when you have the opportunity, just to confirm or disconfirm.

Answer (score 4):

Reading your question the first thing that came to mind was an episode of [*Justified*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1489428/), specifically [S02E01 "The Moonshine War"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1649567/?ref_=ttep_ep1). It would have been out at around the right time. There are no supernatural elements to the show, however it still may be worth a look.

Comment: i strongly agree; item (1) fit the introduction of Loretta perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This couldn't be [Grimm,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm_%28TV_series%29) could it?

[image]

I've never watched the show myself, but I know it circulates similar themes and tropes to both *Supernatural* and the *Whedonverse*.

I read that the rights to [Fables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fables_%28comics%29) spent a long time being passed around, and instead of an adaptation what we ended up with were two poor quality derivatives: Grimm and [Once Upon a Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_%28TV_series%29)

If it isn't, could you at least rule it (*or Once Upon a Time*) out to help others focus the parameters of their search?

Comment: I can certainly rule out _Once Upon a Time_ since I'm all caught up with that. _Grimm_ is a bit more recent than practical for my search, though a few of the early episodes sound like they might be similar.

_Grimm_ sure sounds like a carbon copy of _Supernatural_, too.